# How can I login into an email account, and check the subject of recently delivered emails using Ruby (or Python)?

Tags: python, ruby, email, screen-scraping, web-scraping

Basically, I am try to write a program where I need to login into my email account and check the header of recently delivered emails.

I am a complete novice in terms of this type of stuff and would prefer to do the programming in Ruby. I also have some skill in Python if this would make the task easier. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lots of missing info here. What email service/protocol/etc?

Comment: I am going to try and do it with a yahoo account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for Python's `imaplib` library includes [an example](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example) that does pretty much that:

```
import getpass, imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4()
M.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass())
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])
M.close()
M.logout()
```

You can modify the search string from `'ALL'` to e.g. `(since "24-May-2012")`. I don't think IMAP supports searching by times; you'll probably have to do that filtering yourself.

Comment: According to [this Quora answer](http://www.quora.com/Why-does-Yahoo!-Mail-not-offer-IMAP-access), IMAP for Yahoo works but is not officially supported, instead they recommend the REST API.